# Bluetooth bothered from the next house ... plausible? Solutions?

Tags: emc

I have two computer sitting in a room at one end of my house. I typically connect a bluetooth trackpad to each, and a bluetooth audio box to one.

Every so often, bluetooth communications are disrupted. The trackpads suffer from 'lost connection'; the sound gets choppy and eventually dies. This does not correlate with anything obvious in my house.

Just about when this started to happen, the next house along got some new occupants, who own (!) two Tesla automobiles, and I suspect an arbitrarily large amount of other technology. Their house is at least 100 yards from mine.

Is it even remotely possible that something of theirs is the source of this? It seems wildly unlikely. How would I tell? Is there any practical shielding alternative -- I'm obviously not going to put my office in a Faraday cage.

Note that the problem hits three devices: two trackpads and an audio box. The audio box doesn't even use batteries, so batteries are not a reasonable explanation. The two computers are Macs with builtin bluetooth. There is a USB-3 hub connected to one, but this happens even when the only things plugged into the hub are a keyboard and an ethernet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A distance of 100 yards (and combination with one or two walls, I assume) should in practice be more than enough to prevent the radio interference issues that you suspect. Devices in the 2.5 GHz ISM band (which is what your Bluetooth devices are using) are not allowed to transmit more power than +20 dBm (depending on the country) which is not much. I'm sure the FCC has also checked that Tesla cars don't emit more than what is allowed. Also, Bluetooth is specifically designed to be quite immune to interference (it changes channel 1600 times per second).

So I expect that the issues you have are caused by something else. Have you checked the batteries, sometimes the battery contacts get oxidized a little, you can use an eraser (pencil eraser) to clean that up. Maybe the devices are not receiving each other properly, maybe you have to re-position the receiver. If it's a USB receiver, try using a USB extension cable.

Comment: Thanks, but see edits. I have no problem exonerating my neighbor, but that leaves me in the weeds.

Comment: Regarding the Macs with the built in BT, do you know where the antennas are located in these Macs. Do they have an external antenna or an option for that. If so try re-locating the antennas.

Comment: The laptop antenna is known to be back by the hinge. The puzzle to me is the time variation. Reorienting the laptop doesn't seem to change anything. The antenna on the hockey puck is inside towards the center.

Answer (score 1):

100 yards is quite a high range for most of the usual suspect interfering devices. One possibility though is ethernet-over-mains devices, whose effects can be amplified through the mains wiring acting as an antenna and could be transmitted between properties.

I can't really think of an easy way of measuring this without special equipment. Some devices will tell you SNR which gives you some idea. Turning off the power to your house (mains breaker) and seeing if that makes a difference could implicate the ethernet-over-mains - or it could be some other device in your house.

Comment: Are you suggesting that my neighbor might have ethernet-over-mains? And it might leak across to my house? Because I haven't got that. I've got separate ethernet wiring.